# Can't create an image file in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, javax.imageio

What I need to do is I have a input image file and I need to change it as user's parameters. For example if user wants to make it %30 darker, first I get all pixels with their RGB values and store them in an 2D array. Sample array given below.

```
114 121 140     //Pixel 1
114 121 140     //Pixel 2
114 121 140     //Pixel 3
     .
     .
     .
50 57 83        //Pixel 2073601
```

After that I overwrite that RGB values (in our case if RGB values are 10:10:10, new values will be 7:7:7). Everything from that point is ok. But now I'm facing some difficulties about creating my output.jpg file using my new array of information. When I run my function, it does not creates any output.jpg file. Here is my function.

```
public static void createFinalImage(int height, int width, String[][] rgbArray, String outputFile) {
        BufferedImage img;
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        File f;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                String[] data = rgbArray[y][x].split(" ");
                int red = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                int green = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                int blue = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

                int rgb = new Color(red,green,blue).getRGB();
                img.setRGB(x,y,rgb);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            f = new File(outputFile);
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

I cant understand what is the problem and why I cant get darker image using this function. (I know there is always easier and basic ways to do it but this is an multithreading assignment and I must do it like I explained.) If anyone help me, I would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try debugging? What is the `rgb` value you get for each pixel from the data?

Comment: Have you tried providing an absolute filename? My guess is that it *is* creating the file, just not where you expect it.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Of not then you can output the fill path to file to see where it is created, it can be in your home path

Comment: `ImageIO.write(...)` returns a `boolean` indicating whether or not there was a plugin installed that could write the image in the given format. There is always a JPEG plugin installed, but in recent versions of Java it does not write images with alpha channel. Most likely, all you need is to change `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`, and things will work. You don't seem to use the alpha channel anyway.

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes sir. When I debug it the rgb value is -11512478 where red = 80, green = 85, blue = 98.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did not sir. I will try.

Comment: Added as answer below.

Comment: @Roxox you might want to accept Harald's answer, since it solved your problem. Let's give some credit when credit is due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ImageIO.write(...)` methods return a `boolean` indicating whether or not there is a plugin installed that can write the image in the given format. It's good practice to check this value. While there is always a JPEG plugin installed, in recent versions of Java the JPEG plugin no longer supports images with alpha channel. Most other software don't support 4 channel RGBA JPEGs anyway, so it's not a big loss...

All you need is to change `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to a type without alpha, like `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` or `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, and things will work. You don't seem to use the alpha channel anyway.

The important changes:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
       // Manipulate pixels
    }
}

try {
    File f = new File(outputFile);
    if (!ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", f)) {
        System.err.println("No plugin to write " + img + " in JPEG format to " + f);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @HaraldK said, in my function I was using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` as parameter. But since I have no alpha value, I just changed it as `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`. Modified function given below and it works as normal.

```
public static void createFinalImage(int height, int width, String[][] rgbArray, String outputFile) {
        BufferedImage img;
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        File f;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                String[] data = rgbArray[y][x].split(" ");
                int red = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                int green = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                int blue = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

                int rgb = new Color(red,green,blue).getRGB();
                img.setRGB(x,y,rgb);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            f = new File(outputFile);
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
```